# get a path from Jboss property file

Tags: java, jboss

```
public static void loadProperties(){
    InputStream inputStream = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("test.properties");
    try {
        properties = new Properties();
        properties.load(inputStream);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Where should I place my config file to get it working with this code?

Where should I place my property file? How can I create the property file?

Comment: Where does your property file exist?

Comment: where should i palce it , i dont see any folder call WEB_INF

Comment: It should be in your source code -> war file.

Comment: im new to java. what is war file im doing a blueprint project  uisng jboss. i added some java file there ..in java file i added a code to get path at this moment it is hard coded but i want it to get that path from a property file in server

Answer (score 1):

Add the properties file into your war file inside WEB-INF/classes folder.

Then You can read the file

```
public static void loadProperties(){

  InputStream inputStream = this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("test.properties");
     try {
           properties = new Properties();
           properties.load(inputStream);
     } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
     }
}
```

Comment: Thing is i dont see WEB-INF folder in my jboss sever folder

Comment: @MauricePerry i found this code while im googling , where i put my test.property file,

Comment: @SameeraAthukorala in the classpath.

Comment: @MauricePerry what do you mean by class path where i can find it

Comment: @SameeraAthukorala it could be with your `.class` files or in some other directory specified in the classpath.

Comment: i found one file in workplace end with ,classpath  it already have values ,its like xml